# DropWizard Custom Reporter

Tags: java, dropwizard, metrics

I am trying to create a custom reporter for DropWizard Metrics, but cannot find any resource or example that shows how to create one by extending the `ScheduledReporter`. I could extends this class by following the existing reporters (CSV, SLF4J, etc), but then where do I register it?

Here is an extract of the custom Reporter I am trying to register:

```
public class DbReporter extends ScheduledReporter {
    private final Connection connection;
    private final Clock clock;

    public static DbReporter.Builder forRegistry(MetricRegistry registry) {
        return new DbReporter.Builder(registry);
    }

    private DbReporter(MetricRegistry registry, Connection connection, Clock clock, MetricFilter filter, TimeUnit rateUnit, TimeUnit durationUnit) {
        super(registry, "db-reporter", filter, rateUnit, durationUnit);
        this.connection = connection;
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    //...

    public static class Builder {
        private final MetricRegistry registry;
        private Connection connection;
        private TimeUnit rateUnit;
        private TimeUnit durationUnit;
        private MetricFilter filter;
        private Clock clock;

        private Builder(MetricRegistry registry) {
            this.registry = registry;
            this.connection = null;
            this.rateUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
            this.durationUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
            this.filter = MetricFilter.ALL;
            this.clock = Clock.defaultClock();
        }

        public DbReporter.Builder outputTo(Connection connection) {
            this.connection = connection;
            return this;
        }

        public DbReporter.Builder convertRatesTo(TimeUnit rateUnit) {
            this.rateUnit = rateUnit;
            return this;
        }

        public DbReporter.Builder convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit durationUnit) {
            this.durationUnit = durationUnit;
            return this;
        }

        public DbReporter.Builder filter(MetricFilter filter) {
            this.filter = filter;
            return this;
        }

        public DbReporter build() {
            return new DbReporter(this.registry, this.connection, this.clock, this.filter, this.rateUnit, this.durationUnit);
        }
    }
}
```

And, is this the correct way to create a custom Reporter or is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.-

Comment: Yes that is the right approach. You register them the exact same way you register the other ones (see the metrics docs)

Comment: @pandaadb Yes, but I haven't registered anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement them the same way. As for registering, that is usually done in your main application after the Metrics have been instantiated by DW.

For example, in your run method:

```
@Override
    public void run(final Configuration configuration,
                    final Environment environment)  {
        log.info(String.format("Starting %s server with version: %s", getName(), configuration.getVersion()));

        CsvReporter.forRegistry(environment.metrics()).build(new File("path/to/csv"));
    }
```

Hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: You did not understand my question. See the updated question.

Comment: Again: Yes, that is the right way to create your own custom reporter, and see my answer with where and how you would register it. What else do you want to know, because those are the only questions I can see in your post...